# How to show that dividing out polynomial p gives polynomial ring over its zeroes

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I have come across usage of the following statement multiple times in my commutative algebra course, but I cannot find a proof of it in our lecture notes and I'm not sure how to prove it myself.

"Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $R=K[X_1, X_2... X_n]$ its polynomial ring in $n$ variables, $\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Spec}R$ and $V(\mathfrak{p}):=\{r\in K^n: \forall p\in\mathfrak{p}: p(r)=0\}$, the set of zeros of $\mathfrak{p}$. Then $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is the ring of polynomials over $V(\mathfrak{p})$."

I suppose what I am looking for, then, is an isomorphism from $R/\mathfrak{p}$ to $V(\mathfrak{p})[X_1,X_2...X_n]$, but I have no idea how this isomorphism would look like.

Comment: Not exactly, as $V(\mathfrak p)$ is not a ring. I suppose  what is meant is that $R/\mathfrak p$ is the ring of  *polynomial functions*  over $V(\mathfrak p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should interpret it as follows. Let $S$ be the $K$-algebra of $K$-valued functions on $V(\mathfrak{p})$ which can be extended to a polynomial function on $K^n$ (so this $S$ is the "ring of polynomials on $V(\mathfrak{p})$" you refer to). There is a $K$-algebra homomorphism $R \to S$, given by sending a polynomial to the function on $V(\mathfrak{p})$ which it gives rise to. By definition of $S$, this homomorphism is surjective. By definition of $\mathfrak{p}$, we have that $\mathfrak{p}$ is the kernel of this homomorphism. Hence by isomorphism theorems we have $R / \mathfrak{p}$ isomorphic to $S$.